# What is missing from the java bindings of OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv

From [OpenCV's wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/):

> OpenCV is released under a BSD license, it is free for both academic
>   and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python **and soon Java** interfaces

JavaCV, according to [its homepage,](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) seems to support not only the entirety of OpenCV, but various other related libraries:

> JavaCV first provides wrappers to commonly used libraries by researchers in the field of computer vision: OpenCV, FFmpeg, libdc1394, PGR FlyCapture, OpenKinect, videoInput, and ARToolKitPlus.

So, what's missing in it, if anything at all?

Comment: JavaCV seems to show only the C bindings of OpenCV, not the C++ bindings.

Comment: Oh yes, it's the C interface all over: https://code.google.com/p/javacv/#Quick_Start_for_OpenCV

Comment: What's the difference between both sets of bindings, Blender? Aren't they equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't support [OpenCV's GPU module](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV_GPU), which is available through the package **opencv_gpu**.